# Installing dependency in subdirectory of play.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, quasar, codesandbox

can you help me to solve my problem in play.js provided by sandbox. So, i just trying to install my dependency but my package.json is not in the root folder, it stored inside folder called frontend, how I can install them if the package.json inside there  ? I am on ipad pro 11 2021

This is the root folder:
[image]

This is the frontend folder:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There should be 2 package.json, one inside your frontend folder and one inside your root. The one inside your frontend folder is about your frontend stack and packages. The other one inside your root should handle the backend stack.